# SSIS Add number to Duplicate Values in Column to make them Unique

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

My data has some duplicate records in only a single column. I want to filter them after running the data through a script component to take all duplicate values and append incremental numbers to them so they are unique.

Is it possible to do with with an Aggregate Component?
For example, my data may look like this:

[image: Pre-Number Append]

Column1 and 2 are used as my primary Keys, so I need Column2 to be more unique with it's values.
After Appending numbers to the duplicates, it would look like this (notice 'C' does not have a number):

[image: Post-Number Append]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select tt.*, tt.col2 + '.' + rn  
from ( select t.* 
            , row_number() over (partition by col2 order by ?) as rn
            , count(*) over (partition by col2) as cnt
     ) tt
```

I noticed C does not have a number.  I will leave that exercise to you.  Hint use cnt.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (col2 varchar(20));
INSERT INTO @a VALUES ('a'), ('a') , ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('c');

select aa.*, aa.col2 + '.' + cast(rn as varchar)   
from ( select a.*
            , row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col2) as rn
            , count(*)     over (partition by col2) as cnt 
         from @a a 
     ) aa 
where aa.cnt > 1
order by aa.col2;

update aa 
set aa.col2 = aa.col2 + '.' + cast(rn as varchar)
from ( select a.*
            , row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col2) as rn
            , count(*)     over (partition by col2) as cnt 
         from @a a 
     ) aa 
where aa.cnt > 1; 

select * from @a a
order by a.col2;
```

Comment: WHERE cnt > 1. YOU ARE THE MAN!

Comment: How do I update those values to equal the new duplicate values though?

Comment: Still confused on this. Tried a couple of ways but can't seem to figure this out. How would I do this with update?

Comment: Got it Thank you!